# My mesh is partly hidden in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I was working on my mesh when all of a sudden, I realised it was partly hidden when I go to the Solid or Wireframe mode.
I probably toggle something that only allows to show what's inside that dark grey area but I can't find what it is.
Does any of you have an answer to that problem ?

Cheers,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've accidentally pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, press again to cancel. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (*Cliping Border*) allows you to see only a part of your 3D view.

Comment: Thank you so much 